# Posible to make this Code smaller?

Tags: php, caching, methods

I have this Two Methods

```
private function cacheAdd($id,$data)
{
   $this->minicache->set($id,$data);
}

private function cacheGet($id)
{
   return $this->minicache->get($id);
}
```

Each time if i want to check if the items are cached i have to do something like that:

```
public function getFriendIds()
  {

 $info = $this->cache->minicache->getInfo("getFriendIds"); // if its an array then it is cached
    if(is_array($info))
    {
      return $this->cache->cacheGet("getFriendIds"); // return the cached object
    }
     // from here items wasnt cached
    else
    {
      $this->cache->cacheAdd("getFriendIds",$this->twitter->getFriendIds());  // so add to cache
      return $this->cache->cacheGet("getFriendIds"); // and return the cached items
    }
  }
```

But i think there is a simple method to do this right?

I thought something like this:

```
$this->cache->docache($this->myitems());
```

and method docache takes just the method and converts the methodname to string and checks if the item is already cached or not How could that be done?

EDIT:

I implemented this docache method

```
   public function docache($id,$data)
    {
      $info = $this->minicache->getInfo($id);

      if(is_array($info))
      {
      return $this->cache->cacheGet($id); // return the cached object
      }

      else
      {
        $this->cacheAdd($id,$data);  // so add to cache
        return $this->cacheGet($id); // and return the cached items
      }

    }
```

and if i want to call the method i do this.

```
  public function getFriendIds()
  {
      return $this->cache->docache("getFriendIds",$this->twitter->getFriendIds());
  }
```

No this is much smaller isnt it?

Comment: What are you concerned about? There's not much of the `docache` method to improve in terms of time or space efficiency or even readability. As for simplifying things, class relationships might be a good place to focus. Why is there a cache and a minicache? Why do cache methods delegate to minicache? What does `minicache->getInfo` do that `minicache->get` doesn't? What does `minicache->get` return if `$id` isn't in the cache?

Comment: hmm... realy good questions, minicache is an external library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it `getFriendIds` is one of a slew of methods all of a similar pattern, and what you want to do is make all of them one line (or so) long. In that case, you could refactor you `getFriendIds` into the method you desire:

```
protected function memoize($name, $callable, $args=array()) {
    $info = $this->cache->minicache->getInfo($name); // if its an array then it is cached
    if(is_array($info)) {
        return $this->cache->cacheGet($name); // return the cached object
    } else {
        $this->cache->cacheAdd($name, call_user_func_array($callable, $args));
        return $this->cache->cacheGet($name); // and return the cached items
    }
}

public function getFriendIds() {
    $this->memoize(__METHOD__, array($this->twitter, __FUNCTION__));
}
```

Untested, so there may be some issues.

Comment: isnt that exactly the docache wich i implemeted above?

Comment: Almost. `docache` wasn't in your original question. The main difference is that `memoize` calls the method lazily and only if its value is not cached (note the `call_user_func_array`), while `docache` requires you to always call the method (which defeats the purpose of caching values). Both need a further refinement: add `$args` to cache indexing.

Comment: Do you mean $callable should be type-hinted as an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a few lines here, too.

```
public function docache($id,$data)
{
    $info = $this->minicache->getInfo($id);

    if(!is_array($info))
    {
        $this->cacheAdd($id,$data);  // so add to cache
    }

    return $this->cache->cacheGet($id); // return the cached object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a little smaller (and faster) this way:
It only prevents the $info variable from being stored, so it's a little bit faster. ;)
And the code is much shorter  :p

```
 public function docache($id,$data){
  if(!is_array($this->minicache->getInfo($id))) $this->cacheAdd($id,$data);  // add to cache if theres none
  return $this->cacheGet($id); // and return the cached items
}
```

Edit: *oh, we posted about the same code at the same time :p*